# Magic Method __set() on a Instantiated Object

Tags: php, design-patterns, object, reflection

Ok i have a problem, sorry if i cant explaint it clear but the code speaks for its self.

i have a class which generates objects from a given class name;
Say we say the class is Modules:

```
public function name($name)
{

   $this->includeModule($name);

   try
   {
       $module    = new ReflectionClass($name);
     $instance = $module->isInstantiable() ? $module->newInstance() : "Err";

      $this->addDelegate($instance);
   }

   catch(Exception $e)
   {
      Modules::Name("Logger")->log($e->getMessage());
   }
   return $this;
 }
```

The AddDelegate Method:

```
protected function addDelegate($delegate)
{
    $this->aDelegates[] = $delegate;
}
```

The __call Method

```
public function __call($methodName, $parameters)
{

   $delegated = false;

   foreach ($this->aDelegates as $delegate)
   {
          if(class_exists(get_class($delegate)))
          {

         if(method_exists($delegate,$methodName))
         {
        $method     = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($delegate), $methodName);

        $function   = array($delegate, $methodName);

       return  call_user_func_array($function, $parameters);
          }
     }

   }
```

The __get Method

```
public function __get($property)
    {
        foreach($this->aDelegates as $delegate)
        {
            if ($delegate->$property !== false)
            {
                return $delegate->$property;
            }

        }


    }
```

All this works fine expect the function __set

```
public function __set($property,$value)
    {

        //print_r($this->aDelegates);

        foreach($this->aDelegates as $k=>$delegate)
        {
            //print_r($k);
            //print_r($delegate);
            if (property_exists($delegate, $property))
            {
                $delegate->$property = $value;
            }

        }
        //$this->addDelegate($delegate);
        print_r($this->aDelegates);


    }

class tester
{
  public function __set($name,$value)
    {
        self::$module->name(self::$name)->__set($name,$value);
    }
}


Module::test("logger")->log("test"); //  this logs,  it works
echo Module::test("logger")->path; //prints /home/bla/test/ this is also correct
```

But  i cant set any value to class log like this

```
Module::tester("logger")->path ="/home/bla/test/log/";
```

The path property of class logger is public so its not a problem of protected or private property access.

How can i solve this issue? I hope i could explain my problem clear.

EDIT:
A simple demonstration

```
Modules::Name("XML_Helper")->xmlVersion ="Hello"; // default is 333
$a =  Modules::Name("XML_Helper")->xmlVersion; // now $a should contain "Hello" 
echo $a; // prints 333
```

What i need is

```
Modules::Name("XML_Helper")->xmlVersion ="Hello"; // default is 333
$a =  Modules::Name("XML_Helper")->xmlVersion; // now $a should contain "Hello" 
echo $a; // prints Hello
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple self-contained (i.e. copy&paste-able) example script showing the problem?

Comment: @VolkerK have a look at the example above

Comment: Here is also a print_r  Array
(
    [0] => XML_Helper Object
        (
            [xmlVersion] => hallo
        )

)
which looks correct but where is the error?

Comment: That's not a copy&paste-able, self-contained example (repro code). E.g. `class XML_Helper` is not defined. I would have to somehow put `class Modules` together from the snippets you've provided. Is it `class Module` as in `Module::test("logger")` or  `class Modules` as in `Modules::Name("XML_Helper")`? Or do both classes exist?
You're calling `Modules::Name("XML_Helper")` i.e. a static method call but there's also `public function name($name) { $this->includeModule($name);` which isn't static. Sorry, it's a bit all over the place.

Comment: Ever heard of return new self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise you already said that path is **public**, but it's still worth mentioning: If you're using PHP 5.3.0+, note this quirk of [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists):

> 5.3.0 | This function checks the existence of a property independent of
>   accessibility

In other words, if you check `if (property_exists($delegate, $property))`, you have no guarantee you have access to `$delegate->$property` for writing (or reading, for that matter, but you *are* trying to write).

As for actual troubleshooting: You could try checking if your `if (property_exists($delegate, $property))` statement actually executes. If it doesn't, check the [case](http://php.net/manual/function.property-exists.php#68691) of `$property`.

Sidenote: It's fairly hard to read the code you posted up, which makes it a bit of a pain to troubleshoot. Could you edit your post and indent it properly?

Answer (score 1):

> The path property of class logger is public so its not a problem of
>   protected or private property access.

That's your problem.  From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

```
__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
```

That suggests that `__set()` is not called for public properties.